# More efficient way to do multiple parents

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more efficient way to do the following?

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass('finished');
```

Note that I need the `parent` concept, because I have multiple similar items on the page.

Comment: `parents('anyCssSelector')`

Comment: Also [`.closest(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1)

Comment: Whether there is something more efficient depends on *why* you needed to use this in the first place… What is `this`, and how does your DOM look like?

Comment: Don't worry about *efficiency*, worry about *maintainability*. That is a nightmare to write, much less maintain .. consider designing such elements/structure that a common factor can be employed to do said task simpler.

Comment: You've not defined what you mean by *"efficient"*. Do you mean fewer characters?

Comment: ...if you want both character, and computational efficiency, ditch jQuery and write your own function, like: `function up(node, n) { while (node && n--) { node = node.parentNode; } return node;}` Then you can just do `$(up(this, 4)).addClass(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to get the *Nth* parent, you can mix [`.parents(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), noting that `:eq(0)` gets the 1st item:

```
$(this).parents(':eq(4)').addClass('finished');
```

Comment: Well, that's shorter, but it's less efficient as it searches all parents?

Answer (score 3):

If this is something you use a lot, and adding proper selectors isn't an option, you could just create your own method to get what you want as well :

```
$.fn.parent_num = function(num) {
    var elem = [];
    this.each(function() {
        var el = this;
        while(num>0) {
            if (el.parentNode) el = el.parentNode;
            num--;
        }
        elem.push(el);
    });
    return $(elem || this);
};
```

to be used like :

```
$(this).parent_num(5).addClass('finished');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/exnNd/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have any way to get the element with a CSS selector, you can do this:

```
$(this).parents('selector');
```

[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: It needs to be `parents` not `parent` here.

Comment: jQuery API: `The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. `

Comment: Won't do the right thing if the selector matches multiple ancestors, but that's usually unlikely.